# TemplateSelector doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have `Items Control`, but I want improve this code for working with different types of input data.

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="control"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
              ItemTemplate="{x:Bind CellTemplate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SimpleSelector}}">

    <!--I want make like this-->
    <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    ContentTemplate="{Binding SelectedCollageTemplate, Converter={StaticResource CollageTemplateSelector}}" />
    <!-- -->
<!--now I have this-->
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <controls:SimplePanel SelectedCollage="{Binding SelectedCollage, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedCollagePattern="{Binding SelectedCollagePattern}">
        <controls:SimplePanel.Background>
     <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                 ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/Background/5.jpg" />
        </controls:SimplePanel.Background>
            </controls:SimplePanel>          
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- -->
</ItemsControl>


</Grid>
```

As you can see I want change hardcode to more flexible way and use `Template selector`

I create selector:

```
<templateSelector:CollageTemplateSelector x:Key="CollageTemplateSelector"
                                      SimpleTemplate="{StaticResource SimpleTemplate}"
                                      ShapeTemplate="{StaticResource ShapeTemplate}"/>
```

And added `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SimpleTemplate">
<controls:SimplePanel
                  SelectedCollage="{Binding SelectedCollage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedCollagePattern="{Binding SelectedCollagePattern}">
    <controls:SimplePanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/Background/5.jpg" />
    </controls:SimplePanel.Background>
</controls:SimplePanel>
```

My converter returns Simple Panel. But when I lauch it my `SimplePanel` doesnt start(I have break point on constructor) and part of code doesnt work. What is my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're setting the `ContentTemplate` of your `ContentControl` to your selector; you should set the `ContentTemplateSelector` property instead.
2. In your `ItemsControl` you're setting `ItemsTemplate` to something that looks like a template selector; you should set the `ItemsTemplateSelector` property instead.
3. You shouldn't bind to template selectors, but access them as `StaticResource`s.

I don't fully understand the details of what you're trying to do, so here's an example of a `DataTemplateSelector` that works.

To start with, I'm using the following `ItemsSource`, with the intent of making the string "Three" show in red:

```
public string[] ItemsSource => new[]
    {
        "One", "Two", "Three",
    };
```

The template selector has two `DataTemplate` properties that will be set from XAML -- one for "Three" strings; another for all other strings:

```
public sealed class ItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This property is set in XAML.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This property is set in XAML.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTemplate ThreeTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        if ("Three".Equals(item))
        {
            return ThreeTemplate;
        }

        return NormalTemplate;
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }
}
```

The data template selector has two versions of `SelectTemplateCore`. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplatecore.aspx) discusses which one to use under what circumstances:

> If your ItemsControl.ItemsPanel is an ItemsStackPanel or ItemsWrapGrid, provide an override for the SelectTemplateCore(Object) method. If the ItemsPanel is a different panel, such as VirtualizingStackPanel or WrapGrid, provide an override for the SelectTemplateCore(Object, DependencyObject) method.

The XAML (which assigns data templates to the selector's two properties) looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ItemTemplateSelector">
            <local:ItemTemplateSelector.NormalTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ItemTemplateSelector.NormalTemplate>
            <local:ItemTemplateSelector.ThreeTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ItemTemplateSelector.ThreeTemplate>
        </local:ItemTemplateSelector>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelector}">
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

The result looks like this, with the string "Three" shown in red:

[image: ItemsControl]

I hope this is sufficient to put you on the right track.

Comment: The warning about overriding both `DataTemplateSelector` methods really helped. Yes, that page mentions it, but unfortunately, other MS docs pages that describe how to write your own selector do not...